# Excel - Need a report out of a key and value list

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, report, key-value

Posting my first question so pardon me for any silly mistakes. Question:

I have data in excel in this format:
Input list
[image: Input list]

First-column: List of fruits

Second-column: Available numbers

Third-column: Whether to sell or not

What I need is to have a list out of this which gives me list of fruits which are available to sell which means rows with following setting needs to be selected:

First-column: All unique values (in result list, values should not be repeating as we see in original list)

Second-column: It should add all the values for all unique values from first column, see below screenshot for example.

Third-column: It should ignore the rows with this value populated. It should only consider the rows with null values for this column

Which means we should have following result list for above example:
Result list
[image: Result list]

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

[Note: I can understand we need 2 formula for both column in result list but not sure how can we achieve this.]

Comment: Use a pivot table where the "Fruits"  got into the rows. "In-Stock" goes into Values (as a Sum), where the " For-Sell"  acts as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the newest version of Excel you can do something like the below (I assume your existing table runs from A1:C100, and your results table starts in E1):

1. get the unique fruits with `=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$100)`
2. get the count with `=SUM(FILTER($B$2:$B$100, (($A$2:$A$100=$E1)*($C$2:$C$100<>"No"))))`

Comment: This works like a charm, did some beautification work but this saved my day. Thanks a load.

Comment: @AbhinavSinha Then please accept the answer (tick mark it) so the other visitor can know this solved your problem.

Comment: @Harun24HR I did but it needs reputation and my profile is new so it will done automatically I believe once I receive the reputations. Thanks for the suggestion!